# How do I install .netcore on CentOs machine?

Tags: centos, asp.net-core, dnx, .net-core

I'm new to .NET core and I am trying to run some basic examples on a CentOS machine.

I've read the Microsoft Documentation and found these steps to be the closest guide to what I want to do:

http://dotnet.github.io/core/getting-started/

After following these steps I could run a test/sample application but only under mono( e.g.after issuing

$ dnvm use [version] -r mono

followed by

$ dnu restore

and

$ dnx . run

)

When running under .NET Core ($ dnvm use [version] -r coreclr )
I get the following error:

dnx: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by dnx)
dnx: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by dnx)

I tried updating my gcc but to no avail.
I also found that there were some errors when issuing:

$ yum install libunwind8 libssl-dev unzip

The libunwind8, libssl-dev packages where not found.

Are the two related?
Has anyone successfully installed .NET core on CentOS? 
If so could you point me to a guide or explain the process?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your Cent-Os version ? The procedure is quite complex. I have documented it in a word file with a lot of formatting that make the conversion to text response difficult. But, my response to a similar question, with a temporary link to this document was unfortunately deleted by moderators, because StackOverflow policy don't accept answers with simple reference to external link :(

Comment: I am using CentOS 6.6. I've also found this: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/806

Which basically says that, for the time being core clr does not work with Unix.

Comment: The installation worked for me on centos 6.5. I may transmit the documented procedure, i.e. a word document by a mean of your choice, ftp, e-mail, ... except through an (unaccepted) stackoverflow link. With this procedure, you may also create a directory to put on a CD or a USB key, for an off-line installation.

Comment: @Graffito - Can you or someone make your document available to the public please? I'd like to get it working under RHEL myself and hoping your doc will help. Thanks!

Comment: @rottyguy: link to the [Mono install on Centos 6.5 document](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1541943/dotnet/general-dotnet/mono/installing-mono-on-centos-6-5-a/#post8376239)

Comment: I'm pretty close to getting .NET on CoreCLR running (beta7) on CentOS 7, but I am at the point where I need to install libunwind8, libssl-dev, libcurl3-dev, and zliblg on CentOS.

On Ubuntu: sudo apt-get --yes install libunwind8 libssl-dev libcurl3-dev zlib1g  works fine.

I realize this is likely where I need to update the package repos or something, but I am having trouble discovering HOW YOU DISCOVER what repo a package might be in.

On Ubuntu 14.04, I have 1.0.0-beta7 coreclr running and serving the projects from generator-aspnet.

If I get it working, I'll provide a complete answer.

Comment: I believe I have it.  Answer below.

Comment: As of today Feb'14, 2016 
`dnvm` `dnx` and `dnu` is being replaced by `dotnet` cli, so if anyone want to get developer builds try catching up following link https://github.com/dotnet/cli

Answer (score 5):

You can install .NET Core on CentOS 7 now using the following steps:

```
yum install centos-release-dotnet
yum install rh-dotnet20
```

To use it:

```
scl enable rh-dotnet20 bash
dotnet --info
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the script I use to install CoreCLR on CentOS 7. I have been testing this against two installs on VirtualBox:

**My test VMs**

CentOS 7 with GNOME Desktop and networking turned on

CentOS 7 with networking turned on (almost a minimal install, all you get is a terminal, but your network card works so you can download stuff)

I roll back to the clean install point to repeat the tests.

**Yum packages**

Note the original poster was stuck trying to figure out the yum versions of the CoreCLR dependencies.  I believe I have done this.  At this point, I've had no problems, but CoreCLR is experimental and we're on beta 7 for this answer.

Note that it is harmless to run all of these steps on the CentOS install with GNOME desktop installed, but I do note in "comments" what you don't need on each.

This script never installs Mono and should be good for playing around with CoreClr.  That said I have put both on a machine and it's working, but it's out of scope of the answer.

```
## Get DNVM
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh

## install unzip before installing any dnx versions
## (appears to already be installed on CentOS with GNOME)
sudo yum install -y unzip

## Install CoreCLR latest
dnvm install latest -r coreclr

## install libuv
## dnu restore won't operate without this
## (curl already latest version, but ASP.NET on Linux docs currently have this... harmless)
sudo yum -y install automake libtool curl
curl -sSL https://github.com/libuv/libuv/archive/v1.4.2.tar.gz | sudo tar zxfv - -C /usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src/libuv-1.4.2
sudo sh autogen.sh
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/src/libuv-1.4.2 && cd ~/
sudo ldconfig

## libunwind.x86_64 is in the epel-release repository
## (Not necessary on GNOME, minimal install does not have this installed)
sudo yum -y install epel-release

## Install these CoreCLR dependencies before dnu restore
sudo yum -y install libunwind gettext libcurl-devel openssl-devel zlib
```

**Libuv can't be found**

So after you do all this, you can use the yeoman asp.net generators to get a project.  I generally test with the ConsoleApplication and the WebApplicationBasic.  However, when you try the WebApplicationBasic with

```
dnx kestrel
```

It blows up because kestrel wants to use libuv and can't load it.  One way to solve this problem is to set an environment variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib.

But I was not satisfied with this.  Thanks to [paule96](https://github.com/paule96) on GitHub, I learned you could create symbolic links so libuv can be found when kestrel runs:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 /usr/lib64/libdl
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libuv.so /usr/lib64/libuv.so.1
```

If you want to know how to install node, yeoman, and the aspnet-generators, use this:

```
## rpm for node 0.12 on centos from nodesource
sudo rpm -ivh https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_0.12/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-0.12.7-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm 

## yeoman and aspnet generators
sudo npm install -g yo
sudo npm install -g generator-aspnet
```

Respectfully, I would ask the original poster to change the question to mention this is for ASP.NET beta 7.  There are still breaking changes to be made and I will likely have to update my scripts.  But if the question clearly states this, we won't have to worry about the answer becoming stale.

For example: 
How to setup ASP.NET 5 Beta 7 on CoreCLR for CentOS? 
or
How to setup Beta 7 .NET CoreCLR on CentOS?

I would also ask to consider adding the asp.net-5 tag, unless you really don't think your question applies to that.

Comment: beta 8 appears to have breaking changes.  The ASP.NET team removed instructions for CoreCLR on CentOS and variants for beta 8.  Still, it works if you get a beta 7 dnx.

Comment: Beta 8 (and higher) just needs one more library - `libicu`. But it needs a specific version of it (52), and you can't upgrade the installed version, so you need to hack it in sideways. http://fsoikin.blogspot.com/2015/12/getting-coreclr-running-on-centos.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the doc but the question both the OP & I had was regarding Microsoft .net impl and not Mono.  As many may know, Microsoft opened sourced .Net in early 2015 and is actively trying to make it xplat.  Please see:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr

https://github.com/aspnet/home